# TypeScript Error: 'children' not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes' - React Component Issue

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion, typeerror

Through error message "Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'" typically arises in React components when JSX elements receive props that aren't recognized or expected. This error specifically denotes a mismatch between the expected properties and the actual props received by a JSX element, often related to rendering child components or applying properties incorrectly within React components.

I attempted to render a React component with certain props, including 'children' and 'className'. However, the error "Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'" appeared. I expected the component to render without any TypeScript error related to unrecognized props or attributes.

here my codebase...!

```
import React from "react";

interface TypographyProps extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLElement> {
  variant: "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6" | "p" | "p1" | "p2";
  font?: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const Typography: React.FunctionComponent<TypographyProps> = ({
  variant,
  children,
  className,
  font,
  ...restProps
}) => {
  const variantMapping = {
    h1: {
      variant: "h1",
      classes:
        "2xl:text-[58px] lg:text-5xl md:text-4xl sm:text-3xl text-2xl leading-normal font-lato_bold",
    },
    h2: {
      variant: "h2",
      classes:
        "2xl:text-5xl lg:text-3xl md:text-2xl text-xl font-lato font-bold",
    },
    h3: {
      variant: "h3",
      classes:
        "2xl:text-4xl lg:text-2xl md:text-xl text-lg font-lato font-bold",
    },
    h4: {
      variant: "h4",
      classes:
        "2xl:text-[32px] lg:text-xl sm:text-lg text-lg font-lato !font-bold ",
    },
    h5: {
      variant: "h5",
      classes:
        "2xl:text-2xl md:text-lg sm:text-base text-sm font-lato font-medium",
    },
    h6: {
      variant: "h6",
      classes: "2xl:text-xl lg:text-base text-sm font-lato font-medium",
    },
    p: {
      variant: "p",
      classes:
        "2xl:text-lg xl:text-base md:text-sm text-xs font-lato font-medium",
    },
    p1: {
      variant: "p",
      classes: "2xl:text-base md:text-sm text-xs font-lato font-regular ",
    },
    p2: {
      variant: "p",
      classes: "2xl:text-sm text-xs font-lato font-regular ",
    },
  };

  const classes = variantMapping[variant]?.classes || "";
  const Component = variantMapping[variant]?.variant || "p";
  return (
    <Component className={`${classes} ${className}`} {...restProps}>
      {children}
    </Component>
  );
}

Typography.defaultProps = {
  className: "",
  variant: "p",
};

export default Typography;
```